# Awk script for substracting from the above field

Tags: unix, awk

Hi I have my input file with one field:

```
30
58
266
274
296
322
331
```

I need the output to be the difference of 2nd and 1st rows(58-30=28) and 3rd and 2nd rows(266-58=208) and so on.
my output should look like below:

```
30 30
58 28
266 208
274 8
```

any help please?

Comment: well it can be anything.but i just thought that it should be a simple thing awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data=`cat file | xargs`
echo $data | awk '{a=0; for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) { print $i, $i-a; a=$i}}'

30 30
58 28
266 208
274 8
296 22
322 26
331 9
```

**Update upon comment** Without `cat/xargs`:

```
awk '{printf "%d %d\n", $1, $1-a; a=$1;}' file
```

Comment: That's a really convoluted way to read the file.  Why not `awk '{print $1, $1-a; a=$1}' file` ??

Comment: @glenn because `awk '{print $1, $1-a; a=$1}' file` doesn't work on my awk :) Updated, thanks.

Comment: @glenn: You should post yours as an answer because it's the correct one. khachik: What version of awk is yours and what does glenn's script do when you run it. It's *very* basic AWK and should run on any version.

Comment: @Dennis it outputs ` 30`, ` 28` i.e the first column is empty. It is a builtin [awk in mac Leopard](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.5/man1/awk.1.html) I couldn't find its version...

Comment: Does it do that with `awk '{print $1}'`?

Comment: @Dennis it prints normally with `{print $1}`, with the `for` loop I posted in my answer, but glenn's code leaves the first column empty...

Comment: Sorry to keep after this, but it's *really* odd. What does `awk '{print NF}'` do? It sounds to me like you've got something odd in your input data. You shouldn't have to iterate over the fields when there's only one field per record.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the for loop from Khachick's answer as Awk will go through all the rows anyway. Simpler is:

```
cat file | awk '{ BEGIN { a=0 }; { print $1, $1-a; a=$1 }'
```

However it is also possible to skip the first row that you don't really want by initialising a variable in the BEGIN block and not doing the print if the variable is so initialised before changing its value. Sort of like:

```
BEGIN { started=0 }; { if(0 == started) { started = 1 } else { print $1, $1-a } }
```

Comment: Useless use of cat: put the filename as a parameter to awk.  Also, you don't need to explicitly declare `a=0` -- an uninitialized variable implicitly has value 0.

Comment: Habit. I usually need to run sed a couple of times on the file contents and then have a huge awk program, so it's clearer and easier to write it using "cat file" at the beginning. I didn't know about variables being initialised to 0, plus I'm a control freak C programmer :) I like it to be explicit.

Comment: You don't even need to use a variable of your own. AWK provides one for just that purpose: `NR`. So you can do `NR>1{print $1, $1-a} {a=$1}`. By the way, that assignment is missing from your second example (you could also use `a` for double duty instead of `started`).

Comment: The second example was just for the idea of initialising a variable to use as marker that a task had been completed. You are right that NR would work better here though. I'm more used to parsing files that have arbitrary lines in them that I just want to ignore.